# Flutter ObjectBox: Is List<String> supported for property converters?

Tags: flutter-objectbox

The [Flutter ObjectBox docs](https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/custom-types#list-array-types) state:

> ObjectBox (Java, Dart) has built-in support for String lists. ObjectBox for Java also has built-in support for String arrays.

However, using a `List<String>` in a converter triggers the following warning:

> [WARNING] objectbox_generator:resolver on lib/model/diary_day.dart:
> Skipping property 'doneExercises': type 'List' not supported, consider creating a relation for @Entity types (https://docs.objectbox.io/relations), or replace with getter/setter converting to a supported type (https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/custom-types).

So the question now is, is this a bug, or am I misunderstanding the docs?

Just for reference, the converter looks like:

```
late List<DiaryExercise> doneExercises = [];

List<String> get dbDoneExercises {
  List<String> retVal = [];
  for (DiaryExercise thisExercise in doneExercises) {
    retVal.add(jsonEncode(thisExercise.toJson()));
  }
  return retVal;
}

set dbDoneExercises(List<String> jsonStrings) {
  for (String thisJson in jsonStrings) 
    DiaryExercise exercise = DiaryExercise.fromJson(jsonDecode(thisJson));
    doneExercises.add(exercise);
  }
}
```

Comment: List<String> is supported, however the warning is about List<DiaryExercise>. As you added a converter, you might want to add `@Transient()` to `doneExercises` to silence the warning. I will update the docs as well.

Comment: @Uwe-ObjectBox Thank you very much for the clarification. ObjectBox is pretty awesome btw.. Thanks for providing it.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, it's just a warning. A look into `objectbox-model.json` revealed the `List<String>` converter is used.